# How to check if a user is subscribed to my telegram channel or not using telethon

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I want to know if a user with specific id is joined in my telegram channel which I'm admin in it using telethon. I already tried getting list of all users of my channel but it returns at most 200 users. I need to check user by user that if it is joined or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [GetParticipantRequest](https://tl.telethon.dev/methods/phone/get_group_participants.html) to check if the user is in chat. If not, it would return an error: `telethon.errors.rpcerrorlist.UserNotParticipantError`.

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to [`client.get_permissions`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.chats.ChatMethods.get_permissions) (this one will also work in small groups).

Comment: Please add some more information inside your answer, like code snippet

Answer (score 0):

This work for my.

```
    class GetParticipantsInChannels(object):
        __all_participants:list
        def load_participants_users(self, session, api_id, api_hash, 
            channel_username):
            all_participants=[]
            with TelegramClient( session, api_id, api_hash) as client:
                channel = client.get_entity(channel_username)
                offset=0
                while True:
                    participants = client(
                        GetParticipantsRequest(
                            channel,
                            ChannelParticipantsSearch(''),
                            offset,
                            limit=16000,
                            hash=0
                        )
                    )
                    if not participants.users:
                        break
                    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
                    offset += len(participants.users)
            self.__all_participants=all_participants

participantsChannel = GetParticipantsInChannels()
participantsChannel.load_participants_users( session, 
                    api_id, api_hash, channel_username)
usernames = participantsChannel.get_usernames()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
async def is_participant(channel, user) -> bool:
    offset_user = 0
    limit = 100

    channel_entity = await client.get_entity(channel)
    while True:
        participants = await client(GetParticipantsRequest(
            channel_entity,
            ChannelParticipantsSearch(user),
            offset=offset_user,
            limit=limit,
            hash=0
        ))
        if not participants.users:
            break
        if participants:
            return True
    return False
```

yo, this my code, it work.

But it only use username, Im still looking for how to use IDs.

Perhaps it is a limitation of Telegram, and even if I do so, I will only return 200 messages. Please let me know if you understand.